# Combine chart data if category name is the same - JavaFX

Tags: charts, javafx

I have an observable list of chart data which is created automatically.  Is there any way to automatically combine the data which has the same category name in to one category? 
The reason I need this is since the observable list of data is created directly form a table in a SQL database, I can not know if the user actually wants to show a combined view or each category and value separately in the chart.

Say I have the following data:
[image]

[image]

Instead of Bordeau-1 appearing this many times, I want all the values combined in to one pie called Bordeau-1, the same goes for Boredeau-2 and 3.

This is the code I use to automatically create data from the ObservableList which represents a table:

```
 ObservableList<PieChart.Data> pieChartData
                = 
FXCollections.observableArrayList(EasyBind.map(observableListData, rowData -> {
                    String name = (String) rowData.get(0);
                  Double value = Double.parseDouble(rowData.get(1));
                    return new PieChart.Data(name, value);
                }));
```

Comment: Is all the data available before the Pie Chart is displayed, or is data added/removed/modifed after the pie chart is created?

Comment: It's available before the PieChart is displayed. If the user modify the data he also has to create a new piechart.

Comment: If there is any way to check for it in the Easybind mapping, I guess it always should happen before the pieChart is displayed anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you load the data, store it in a `Map<String, Double>`, and use the `Map.merge(...)` method to add or combine new values.

So in the code where you are loading the data from the database, you do this:

```
public Map<String, Double> loadDataFromDatabase() {
    Map<String, Double> data = new HashMap<>();
    // for each row in database:
        // get name and value from row
        data.merge(name, value, Double::sum);
    // end for...
    return data ;
}
```

Once you have loaded all the data into the map, you need to convert it to an `ObservableList<PieChart.Data>`. I don't think there's a cute way to do this in `EasyBind`, and if you're loading all the data at the start anyway, then you don't need the bound list. You can do something like:

```
ObservableList<PieChart.Data> pieChartData =
    data.entrySet().stream()
    .map(entry -> new PieChart.Data(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()))
    .collect(Collectors.toCollection(() -> FXCollections.observableArrayList()));
```

If the original map may get modified after the pie chart is created, you will need to make it an `ObservableMap`, register a listener with it, and update the pie chart data accordingly if the map changes. If you need this, it might be worth requesting the appropriate functionality in the EasyBind framework. Something like a method

```
public static <K, V, T> ObservableList<T> mapToList(ObservableMap<K, V> map, Function<Map.Entry<K, V>, T> mapping);
```

Comment: Now I'm wondering why the Pie Chart was ever implemented with a list, and not a map...

Comment: Thanks! But how can I add the data to the map in a efficient way? I now just use the EasyBind and return name and value

Comment: for(PieChart.Data data : pieChart.getData())
{
  addNewDataPoint(data.getName(), data.getPieValue());
}This I what I made now, but guess there is a better way?

Comment: Sorry, you misunderstood the context for my code. Represent the data from the database as a `Map<String, Double>`, then in your FX code convert the `Map` to an `ObservableList<PieChart.Data>` as shown. Updated to make it clearer (I hope).

Comment: Right now the code uses an ObservableList with all the rows and columns. Then, when the user wants a for example pieChart he selects which column represents the name and which represents values. Then I do the easybind to create a new observableList with the data to the PieChart, using the rowData.get(0) and rowData.get(1), where 0 and 1 are columns. I guess I now have to replace the easybind with the Map, but how can I get only the two columns the user chose and add them to the map?

Comment: Ah, ok. Then I think what you did in the earlier comment was probably right.

Comment: So there isn't any way to do this more efficient? Because it seems a bit slow to first get the Names and Values out from the ObservableList in to a new observableList with EasyBind, then loop through the whole data adding it to a map,then adding it back to an observablelist which can be used in the pieChart?

Comment: Okay, I found a real nice way. Thank you again James_D. Saved the day :)